# How to make this partially collapsable Navbar show items where I want on Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 4 Navbar to only collapse partially.

Basically I want some items aligned to the right to remain visible at all times, while most of the Navbar items to the left will collapse into a menu if you try to open the website on mobile.

The problem is that, when you expand that menu, the collapsed elements are showing before the fixed menu, as you'd expect them to, but I want them to show below, for obvious aesthetic reasons.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfm70xLe/

Desired outcome while expanded:

[image]

Desired outcome while acessing the collapsed items:

[image]

I've been playing around with the disposition of the elements aswell as trying `float-right` and `float-right` but it's proven ineffective, I'm not sure how to proceed with this without making drastic changes to the foundation Bootstrap laid for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the navbar-header div up before the navbar-collapse div in the HTML it will work. Then you will just need to use [order](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) to move the navbar-header to the right for sizes larger than medium.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that CSS property, this worked great. Also it seems Bootstrap has a class specific to apply `order: 1` only when the menu is not collapsed called `order-md-1`. http://jsfiddle.net/sfm70xLe/14/

Comment: Ah right, Bootstrap has that helper class.
Keep in mind that the "order" property is for flexbox child items.